# adding conditional variables

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am working with NBA df. I have columns with total stats for each player. 
Stats(columns), total careeer only, are: games played, points, rebounds... There's 17 of them.
Here's what it looks like for Michael Jordan.

| player | games played | points | rebounds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael Jordan | 1072.0 | 32292 | 6672 |

I'm trying to develop a model (neural network???) that will point a future All Star player.
My question is should I add columns with career averages for each player? So that I would divide each career total statistic by 'games played', e.g.:

'points' / 'games' = 'points per game' and repeat it for each total staistic.

Would that be something helpful for my model or would it be unnecessary?

How should I know if adding columns is an added value to a model?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking, to identify people who will become all star players based on their current stats using a model of past players, both all star and not, yes, you will likely need to do some feature engineering if all you have is career summaries.

You cannot compare the career totals of someone with 15 years in to someone with 2 years in meaningfully. You also will need to label your All-Stars and your Average-Joes. Your model will need labels to help it build an understanding of what constitutes and All-Star player.

You might also consider variables that are not just numeric. Whether or not a certain number of rebounds is high or not may be affected by the position. Few weak forwards rebound as much as a center does, so there should be something to account for this in your model.

You could build a neural network. But a solid logistic regression (1- All Star, 0 - not) might be a good starting place, if for no other reason than you get to see, in your model summaries ,the impact of the variables on the class labels and play around with feature engineering.

You may end up using another model down the line, or you may not, but it would not be a bad place to start because you will be able to see what defines a class and tweak the model.